# How can I parse the "payload" property of a NotificationResponse object obtained from Flutter Local Notification package in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, push-notification, flutter-local-notification

I have tried using json decode, but it throws a FormatException. The "payload" property contains a malformed JSON string with the following structure:

```json
{
    idReport: 15, 
    idEmbarcacion: 627, 
    body: El reporte No. 15 del buque No. 627 requiere información, 
    title: Reporte requiere información, observacion: prueba
}
```

The JSON string is sent from the server as part of a push notification, and has the following correct structure:

```
{
    "to": "token",
    "notification": {
        "title": "Reporte requiere información",
        "body": "El reporte No. 15 del buque No. 627 requiere información "
    },
    "data": {
        "idReport": 15,
        "idEmbarcacion": 627,
        "title": "Reporte requiere información",
        "body": "El reporte No. 15 del buque No. 627 requiere información ",
        "observacion": "prueba"
    }
}
```

Comment: you can try encoding the dynamic json and later decode it.